# Centre child node next to two parents on the same height as grandparents

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees

So I am making a tree for my thesis with the following code. I could not find a lot of answers on find how to link a child ("niveaus") to two parents ("soft skills" and "hard skills"), so I solved it this way (see code).  My problem is that the node "niveaus" has to be on the same height as the nodes "profiel" en "competenties". How should I do that?

P.S. I know my code is horrible, but I am quite new to LaTeX and I have never used Tikz before.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    sibling distance=8em,level distance=10em, every node/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,align=center,rounded corners,}, ->, grow=right, edge from parent/.style={draw,-latex}
]
  
  \node{profiel}
    child {node {competenties}
        child{node(sk){soft skills}
            child{node[above right](n){niveaus}}
        }
        child{node(hs){hard skills}
            child[missing] {
             node(n) {niveaus}
            }
        }
    };
\draw (hs) [-latex]-- (n);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please, give a fully compilable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `forest`package:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    draw,
    rounded corners, 
    text depth=0.25ex,
% tree
    grow=0,
    anchor=east,
    s sep=11mm,
% edges
    edge={-Stealth},
            }
[profiel
    [competenties
        [soft skills, name=sf]
        [,coordinate,no edge [niveaus, name=n,no edge]]
        [hard skills, name=hs]
    ]
]
\draw[-Stealth] (sf) edge (n)
                (hs) edge (n);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This one worked perfectly, thanks so much! Only one question: how can I make the arrow from the node "profiel" to the node "competenties" a bit longer?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
sibling distance=8em,
level distance=10em, 
every node/.style={
                    shape=rectangle,
                    draw,
                    align=center,
                    rounded corners,
                    }, 
grow=right, 
edge from parent/.style={
                        draw,
                        -latex
                        }
]

\node{profiel}child {node {competenties}
                child{node(sk){soft skills}
                    }child{node[xshift =3cm](n) {niveaus}edge from parent[draw=none]}
                child{node(hs){hard skills}
                        }   
    };
\draw (hs) [-latex]-- (n);
\draw (sk) [-latex]-- (n);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Why you provide only code fragment and not an MWE?

Comment: same language that the OP understands is better

Comment: well, your answer  is not only for OP, but should help to all others with similar problem. BTW, MWE provide (far) more information as a code fragment, which can gives different result at different documentclass and preamble. well, it is up tp you haw you convinced what is better for OP.